# Trouble in directive template

Tags: angularjs, function, scope, directive, param

i have a **directive** without isolate scope, with this section of his template :

```
<li ng-repeat="filter in listFilters">
<p id="filter{{filter.option}}Container">
    <input ng-keypress="filterPress($event)" ng-model="filterTag['{{filter.option}}']" data-opt="{{filter.option}}" type="text" />
    <label for="filter{{filter.option}}">Filter</label>
    <button ng-click="addTag('{{filter.option}}')">OK</button>
</p>
```

And my **controller** has this :

```
mapCtrl.controller('mapCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http, $window, $sce, $compile) {
$scope.listTags = [];
$scope.filterTag = [];
$scope.addTag = function (opt) {
    if (typeof $scope.filterTag[opt] != "undefined" && $scope.filterTag[opt].trim() != "") {
        if (!$scope.listTags[opt]) {
            $scope.listTags[opt] = []
        }
        if ($scope.listTags[opt].indexOf($scope.filterTag[opt]) == -1) {
            $scope.listTags[opt].push($scope.filterTag[opt]);
            $scope.filterTag[opt] = "";
        }
        $scope.setMarkersVisible();
    }
}}])
```

so, when show the result HTML with the debugger (chrome) it's ok, but if i click the function **addTag** does'nt work. I add a console.log(opt) at first in this function, and the console return ***{{filter.option}}*** or with the debugger i see **addTag("myOpt")**.

I have the same problem in the same directive with this part (see the first html code) :

```
 ng-model="filterTag['{{filter.option}}']"
```

with the debugger i see ***ng-model="filterTag['myOpt']"*** but if i log **filterTag['myOpt']** from my controller **mapCtrl** is undefined....

please help me :(

**I specify : I have to pass this param in addTag**

Comment: Can you build a working plunker and add it to the question? http://plnkr.co/

Comment: Yeah, a plunker would help. Anyway, I'll give it shot. We usually don't use {{ }} inside ng-* tags. You might try replacing filterTag['{{filter.option}}'] by filterTag[filter.option + '']. Maybe it helps.

Comment: You don't need to use the {{ }} for the variable just use ng-click='addTag(filter.option)'.  ng-click is an angular compiled tag so knows about the angular variables in your ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

Thank U Scott, your answer is right!

> You don't need to use the {{ }} for the variable just use
>   ng-click='addTag(filter.option)'. ng-click is an angular compiled tag
>   so knows about the angular variables in your ng-repeat – Scott